# Unable to clone a JSON Array properly using C++ Poco library

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

I would like to clone json objects. 
In order to do the job, I've developped two functions. One for objects and one for arrays.

The method that's clone JSON::Object::Ptr works well.
Here is the code

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr CJsonHelper::cloneJson(Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr obj)
{
    Poco::JSON::Object::Iterator it;
    Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr ptr = new Poco::JSON::Object;
    // loop and copy
    for(it = obj->begin(); it != obj->end(); it++)
        ptr->set(it->first, it->second);

    return ptr;
}
```

The method that's clone JSON::Array::Ptr works but when I stringify the object that's contains the array, I got following error :

```
Can not convert to std::string
```

Here is the code of the function to clone array that's doesn't work

```
Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr CJsonHelper::cloneJson(Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr obj)
{
    Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr copy = new Poco::JSON::Array;
    // loop and copy
    for (auto item = obj->begin(); item != obj->end(); ++item)
    {
        copy->add(item);
    }

    return copy;
}
```

The object pass to function is previsoulsy parsed from faile and is valid

```
{
  "items" : [
  {
    "name" : "object0",
    "position" : {
      "x" : "700.0",
      "y" : "0.0",
      "z" : "250.0"
    } 
  }
  ]
}
```

In the clonse method if I replace the

```
copy->add(item);
```

by

```
copy->add(item->extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>());
```

it's working well but only in this case, I need it to be generic.

I'm sure I've missed something that I don't found because it is working well in clone object method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found my mistake !

I've missed a ***** to go through the auto iterator

```
copy->add(item);
```

becomes

```
copy->add(*item);
```

I post the updated function if it can help someone

```
Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr CJsonHelper::cloneJson(Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr obj)
{
    Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr copy = new Poco::JSON::Array;
    // loop and copy
    for (auto item = obj->begin(); item != obj->end(); ++item)
    {
        copy->add(*item);
    }

    return copy;
}
```